# Finding the difference in 2 strings

Tags: c#, indexof

I have 2 texboxes in a PowerPoint. One original and one edited. I get these to string and break them each up into an array. I then compare them for any differences. For example my original Text box has "This New" and my edited has "Thisss Blaa" the output is then "This Thisss New Blaa". However when my original TextBox has the same word twice e.g. "This This" my output is "This Thiss Blaa" where it should be "This Thiss This Blaa". This only happens when I have 2 of the same words in a string. Has anyone got any ideas how to fix this?

My code is as follows

```
            var q = from original in originalList
                    join editedTmp in editList on original.Id equals editedTmp.Id into g
                    from edited in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        original,
                        edited
                    };
            foreach (var item in q)
            { 



            char delimiter = Convert.ToChar(" ");
            var originalString = item.original.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
            var editString = item.edited.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;

            var firstStringList = originalString.Split(delimiter).ToList();

            var secondStringList = editString.Split(delimiter).ToList();


            foreach (var word in firstStringList)
            {
                if (secondStringList.IndexOf(word) == -1)
                {




                    var indexOfWord = firstStringList.IndexOf(word); //gets the position of the edited word eg. 3.
                                                                     // using indexOfWord+indexOfWord as I need do this if more than one word is added.
                    secondStringList.Insert(indexOfWord + indexOfWord, word);

                    // Insert the word that was not found at position 3 inside secondStringList

                    one.Add(word);


                    }
            }
```

Comment: What is the class of 'one' that you added the words to?

Comment: It's just a list. Doesn't matter in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think you want:

string 1: `This This`
string 2: `Thisss blaa`

To result in: `This Thisss This Blaa`.

The simplest way I achieved this is:

```
var first = "This This";
var second = "Thisss blaa";

var firstSplit = first.SplitBySpace();
var secondSplit = second.SplitBySpace();

var result = string.Join(" ", firstSplit.Zip(secondSplit, (firstString, secondString) => firstString + " " + secondString));
// result = "This Thisss This Blaa"
```

The `SplitBySpace` is this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitBySpace(this string value)
    {
        return value.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

`.Zip` takes two arrays and joins each element at the same position together. So equivalent of doing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
    var newElement = arr1[i] + arr2[i]
    arr3[i] = newElement;
}
// arr1.Length = 10, arr2.Length = 10;
// arr3.Length = 10!
```

However, with that second parameter of `.Zip()` you can define how you create the new element.

#### Integration

```
var q = from original in originalList
        join editedTmp in editList on original.Id equals editedTmp.Id into g
        from edited in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            original,
            edited
        };

foreach (var item in q)
{ 
    var originalString = item.original.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
    var editString = item.edited.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
    var firstSplit = originalString .SplitBySpace();
    var secondSplit = editString .SplitBySpace();

    var result = string.Join(" ", firstSplit.Zip(secondSplit, (firstString, secondString) => firstString + " " + secondString));

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Please note he didn't want the result: *This is isn't*  but the result: *This is This isn't* [e.g. "This This" my output is "This Thiss Blaa" where it should be "This Thiss This Blaa".]

Comment: @OriNachum I re-read his question, and I'm really confused by it now. I'll prob just delete this answer...

Comment: Basically if I have 2 words in a string such as "This This" and I want to compare it with another string "Thisss blaa" it should output "This Thisss This Blaa" however it only outputs "This Thisss Blaa"

Comment: Actually, your code is slick and elegant - why not slightly improve it? Though, he really did just want to fix his own code.
OP, I'd go for @CallumLinington's code with a slight correction to match your requirements

Comment: @CraigGallagher then take my code and just don't do the group by.... `Zip` will do what you need

Comment: @OriNachum I've updated the code

Comment: @CallumLinington does the for loop go in the main code or in the StringExtensions class?

Comment: @CraigGallagher what did you want to do with these new strings? Add them to a list?

Comment: @CallumLinington No I get the 2 strings compare them then added the edited text to the string. I then just want to output the new string.

Comment: @CraigGallagher see integration section

Comment: @CallumLinington `var firstSplit = first.SplitBySpace();` I have an error saying `string does not contain a definition for SplitBySpace`

Comment: @CraigGallagher Yes because you also have to copy in the `StringExtensions` class as well...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135169/discussion-between-craig-gallagher-and-callum-linington).

Comment: @CraigGallagher, Please remember to mark this as the answer to make it clearer.